# Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7 3G (autodeploy.zip not found)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I've tried to install Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 3G. I used [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).
My tablet won't boot with Ubuntu, and I've received in the recovery mod this error message:

```
Checking for autodeploy.zip
autodeploy.zip not found.
```

I've used these commands to do it manually:

```
adb push ./saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+grouper.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
adb push ./saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
```

...but it didn't help.

Tell me please, what can I do to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you provide `ls -l /sdcard/`?

Comment: ~ # ls -l sdcard
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Aug  4 05:33 sdcard -> /data/media

Answer (score 2):

The 'Manual Installation' instructions appear to be incomplete (for a full install).

The two files are used to 'update' an existing install. A 'full install' has 3-4 more steps.

---

### ***Specific to ASUS Nexus 7 3G***

The **Nexus 7 3G** model is **not** yet supported, but can use the standard **Nexus 7** ('grouper') build.

*The tag **`-d grouper`** needs to be present.*

Try using the provided tool, as described on the Wiki.

**`phablet-flash -d grouper -b`** (full install, current) or

**`phablet-flash -d grouper -b --pending`** (full install, untested daily)

*From there, you can probably create the extra manual steps.*

To download ALL files first (without a device attached) use:

**`phablet-flash -d grouper -b -D`** (current)

**`phablet-flash -d grouper -b -D --pending`** (untested daily)

---

### **UPDATE: (23-Aug-2013)**

The **ASUS Nexus 7 3G** (and in particular the **32 GB** model) are somewhat different from the base model of the **Nexus 7** ('grouper'). They have support for GSM 3G/4G and other low-level firmware changes.

*Before **Ubuntu Touch** was 'flipped' (still ran Ubuntu in a container inside Android), this did not provide an insurmountable problem. However, the additional features not found in **grouper** were also not available.*

Now with the 'flipped' design, and with current changes to the underlying *Ubuntu Touch* OS and UI, only the base model **Nexus 7** (*grouper*) is currently supported.

See also:

[Latest two images will not install on Nexus7 (32GB + 3G), but older were Ok](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240242/latest-two-images-will-not-install-on-nexus7-32gb-3g-but-older-were-ok)

> The latest two (newest) daily images will not install on my Nexus 7, 32GB + 3G. The older versions work fine. Background looks like coloured snow. ..

[Nexus 7 3G [2012] problem with ubuntu touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335946/nexus-7-3g-2012-problem-with-ubuntu-touch)

> **Nexus 7 3G** is not equivalent to *grouper*.
>
> Nexus 7 is a commercial name that hides a lot of different hardware configurations in it.
>
> If the hardware codename is **tilapia** [2012, 3G] or **razor** [2013] the device will not work without modifications or what people call ports, please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

*and more technical:*

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1079729

> **Ubuntu uninstallable on 32GB 3G Nexus 7**
>
> Nexus7 variants without 3G support map their user data partition (UDA) to mmcblk0p9, where variants with 3G support map UDA to mmcblk0p10 ..

Comment: I've tried **phablet-flash -d grouper -b**, but it didn't help.

The device does not boot further label Google.

At recovery mod, I see: 

`"autodeploy.zip not found". `

After pushing saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+grouper.zip by **adb push**, I select **install zip from sdcard**.

I've checked this file

`$ adb shell

~ # ls /sdcard

autodeploy.zip`

After this, I recieve:

`Finding update package...

Opening update package...

Installing update...

Install from sdcard complete`

But after adb reboot, I see only Google label.

What I did wrong?

Comment: same problem with me.no answer from anyone.