# Nexus 7 3G [2012] problem with ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am having problems after installing ubuntu touch on my Nexus 7 3G

I tried using the command to install ubuntu touch

```
sudo pablet-flash cdimage-touch -d grouper -b
```

But after installing, it doesn’t boot. It's stuck at the Google splash screen. .
I can go to the recovery menu. I tried to flash packages manually with no joy.

I can login to ubuntu via terminal connected using the usb cable

```
$ adb shell


BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8.1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

but it doesn’t show anything on the screen

In the recovery mode, I can connect via shell commands again but commands are very limited

```
~ # pwd
/
~ # uname -a
Linux localhost 3.1.10-6-grouper #23-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 16 18:58:39 UTC 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus 7 3G is **not** equivalent to `grouper`.

Nexus 7 is a commercial name that hides a lot of different hardware configurations in it.

If the hardware `codename` is `tilapia` or `razor` the device will not work without modifications or what people call ports, please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

To find out what device you can run

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.device
```

Comment: I follwed the Ubuntu Touch wiki. It gives a command to run for Nexus 7 3G. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install .  Deploying Image to Device section.  I have been successful in the past in getting UT to boot in Nexus 7 3G. This stopped working after flipped images became default

Answer (score 0):

Try `--pending` and see if it works:

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch -d grouper -b --pending
```