# Argument in phablet-flash for Nexus73G

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I trying install Ubuntu-touch on Nexus 7 3G, using [Touch Install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).
But on the step 4, I received an error:

```
~ $ sudo phablet-flash -d grouper -b
phablet-flash: error: argument : invalid choice: 'grouper' (choose from 'cdimage-touch', 'cdimage-legacy', 'ubuntu-system', 'community')
```

Comment: ~ $ sudo phablet-flash cdimage-touch
INFO:phablet-flash:Device detected as tilapia
ERROR:phablet-flash:Unsupported device, autodetect fails device

Comment: As of **March 2013** use of the **`phablet-flash`** tool has been deprecated, and you should use **`ubuntu-device-flash`**. Support (as reference hardware) for the **Nexus 7** (original model) is also now deprecated. *(see more below)*

Answer (score 1):

As of **version 1.0** (of phablet-tools) the syntax you need changes to:

**`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -d grouper -b`**

*You should not need* `sudo` *for this command.*

---

See: **`phablet-flash -h`** OR http://sergiusens.github.io/posts/updates-to-phablet-flash.html

Verify what version you have with: **`dpkg -s phablet-tools | grep Version`**

*This new version definitely works for **Nexus 7** and **Nexus 10**, but I have not yet tried with **Nexus 7 3G**.*

---

### **UPDATE: (23-Aug-2013)**

The **ASUS Nexus 7 3G** (and in particular the **32 GB** model) are somewhat different from the base model of the **Nexus 7** ('grouper'). They have support for GSM 3G/4G and other low-level firmware changes.

*Before **Ubuntu Touch** was 'flipped' (still ran Ubuntu in a container inside Android), this did not provide an insurmountable problem. However, the additional features not found in **grouper** were also not available.*

Now with the 'flipped' design, and with current changes to the underlying *Ubuntu Touch* OS and UI, only the base model **Nexus 7** (*grouper*) is currently supported.

See also:

[Latest two images will not install on Nexus7 (32GB + 3G), but older were Ok](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240242/latest-two-images-will-not-install-on-nexus7-32gb-3g-but-older-were-ok)

> The latest two (newest) daily images will not install on my Nexus 7, 32GB + 3G. The older versions work fine. Background looks like coloured snow. ..

[Nexus 7 3G [2012] problem with ubuntu touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335946/nexus-7-3g-2012-problem-with-ubuntu-touch)

> **Nexus 7 3G** is not equivalent to *grouper*.
>
> Nexus 7 is a commercial name that hides a lot of different hardware configurations in it.
>
> If the hardware codename is **tilapia** [2012, 3G] or **razor** [2013] the device will not work without modifications or what people call ports, please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

*and more technical:*

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1079729

> **Ubuntu uninstallable on 32GB 3G Nexus 7**
>
> Nexus7 variants without 3G support map their user data partition (UDA) to mmcblk0p9, where variants with 3G support map UDA to mmcblk0p10 ..

---

### **UPDATE: (09-Mar-2014)**

***This question/answer is no longer current.***

- As of **March 2013** use of the **`phablet-flash`** tool has been deprecated, and you should use **`ubuntu-device-flash`**.
- Support (as reference hardware) for the **Nexus 7** (original model) is also now deprecated, with development focused on: **Nexus 4** smartphone, **Nexus 7 (2013)** tablet, and **Nexus 10** tablet.
- *Support for **Galaxy Nexus** is "maintenance only" (major bug fixes).*